# Find total date in ms sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help to find a total day in ms sql 2008 for example I have a course table like following

```
+----------+------------+------------+
|  Course  |  DateFrom  |   DateTo   |
+----------+------------+------------+
| Course1a | 12/22/2015 | 12/22/2015 |
| Course1b | 12/22/2015 | 12/22/2015 |
| Course1c | 12/24/2015 | 12/28/2015 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

and a Holiday table that store holiday which mean no course during that day

```
+-----------+------------+
|   name    |  DateFrom  |
+-----------+------------+
| Christmas | 12/25/2015 |
+-----------+------------+
```

In here I want to have total days for course1 to be 5 days (12/22, 12/24, 12/25(do not count christmas holiday), 12/26, 12/27, 12/28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to use:

```
;WITH tally AS
(
  SELECT TOP 1000 r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1
  FROM master..spt_values
), cte AS
(
  SELECT Course, DATEADD(d, t.r, c.DateFrom) AS dat
  FROM #courses c
  JOIN tally t
    ON DATEADD(d, t.r, c.DateFrom) <= c.DateTo
)
SELECT LEFT(Course, 7) AS Course_Name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT dat) AS Total_Days
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN #holidays h
  ON c.dat = h.DateFrom
WHERE h.DateFrom IS NULL
GROUP BY LEFT(Course, 7);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415634)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╗
║ Course_Name ║ Total_days ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╣
║ Course1     ║          5 ║
╚═════════════╩════════════╝
```

How it works:

- `tally` generates number table (any method)
- `cte` transforms `date_from` and `date_to` to multiple rows
- join with `holidays` table to exclude holiday dates
- `GROUP BY LEFT(Course, 7)` is workaround (your course name should be distinct without suffixes (a,b,c) or you need another column that indicates that 3 courses combined create one course)
- `COUNT` only `DISTINCT` dates to get total days count